# A simple Pop and then load back does not work

Tags: .net, il, ilgenerator

After calling a function, which returns an `object`, I try to store the value on stack in a local variable and then push it back, but it fails with an exception

> Exception has been thrown with a target of invocation

Code is as follows:

```
.....

MethodInfo checked_static = typeof(NameSpace1.Class1).GetMethod(
    "Check", new Type[1] { typeof(object) });
adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, checked_static);
adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3);
adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
adderIL.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, TRUE);

.....
```

If I remove `Stloc_3` and `Ldloc_3` everything works fine, I am lost here.

Comment: Document the exception's InnerException.

Comment: errr, we have to declare the local variable ? doesnt Ldloc_3 upload the value to an array of local variables present to every stack in a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to my question, it appears that you haven't declared your local.  Each method in IL indicates the types of all of the locals that it uses, so you need to declare it using one of the `DeclareLocal` overloads on your `adderIL` instance.  If you haven't declared any other locals, then you'll also need to use `OpCodes.Stloc_0` instead of `OpCodes.Stloc_3` (and likewise for the loads); alternatively you can just use `OpCodes.Stloc` or `OpCodes.Stloc_S` and pass the `LocalBuilder` instance from the `DeclareLocal` call as the second argument to `adderIL.Emit` (in which case the Reflection.Emit library will get the correct index from the local for you).

Comment: aah, i get it, but when can we use Stloc_3 since it is the same as Stloc_0 but at a different index ?

Comment: @KiNGPiN - If you have 4 locals then you access the fourth one using `Stloc_3`; if you've got only one local then you just use `Stloc_0`.